# git "You have divergent branches" when I havent made any changes or commits

Tags: git, git-pull, git-reset

I cloned a repo, then later I want to pull the latest version.
I have made no modifications or commits locally.

However, git pull says this:

fatal: Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.

git status says this:

```
Your branch and 'origin/main' have diverged,
and have 2 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
```

I have not made a commit. Only the author has.

If I do `git log`, I can see all commits are by the original author, not me.

How can I find out why git thinks I have made a commit?

Comment: Someone having rewritten remote history may be the cause. To be checked. (IF someone now has a new history without the last 2 commits but with a newly added one, like after a rebase for instance, even if you didn't **commit** these 2 yourself, they're still detected as "ahead" regarding the remote)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe `git reflog origin/main` says something about forced updates on the remote.

Comment: unfortunately git reflog origin/main doesnt give any output in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Similar to @Jay but a little bit simpler with a command I use quite often.  That said, **I think his answer is awesome. If you upvote mine, I strongly encourage you to upvote his**)

It seems somebody has force-pushed to the remote main branch,
effectively deleting the last two commits known to your local branch and replacing them with a new commit.

You can adjust your local branch to point to the same commit as the remote branch using:
`git reset --hard origin/main`

Answer (score 4):

It seems somebody has force-pushed to the remote `main` branch,
effectively deleting the last two commits known to your local branch and replacing them with a new commit.

If you don't have uncommitted changes, you can adjust your local branch to point to the same commit as the remote branch using

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{upstream}
```

Short version:

```
git reset --hard @{u}
```

Comment: you probably need a `--hard` reset.  Nice to learn about that upstream bit. is upstream a magic tag or a remote name?

Comment: @UpAndAdam Indeed, thanks. And yes, it's magic and refers to the upstream of the current branch. I used the longest version `HEAD@{upstream}` to make it more readable. The shortest way to write it is `@{u}` :)

Comment: @UpAndAdam Btw, you can find `@{upstream}` and other fun things in `git help revisions` :)

Comment: Now I no longer need one of the aliases I had created long ago to do this automatically... i used to say `git rebase origin/\`git gu\``  where `git gu` was an alias for `rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` now I can just say rebase `@{u}` from what you suggest..  i tended not to reset hard unless i really messed up and would just merge forward or rebase and find my junk.

Comment: @UpAndAdam That's great! :) `git rebase @{u}` probably isn't the best example/use-case, as `git rebase` without *any* upstream/branch arguments will default to current branch's upstream and current branch anyway. (Unless I'm just confused :D) If I get new remote commits in a `git fetch` before pushing my own, just `git rebase` will do the trick and locally move my commits on top of the new remote ones. But `@{u}` *can* still be useful for rebase if both `<upstream>` and `<branch>` arguments are specified or for more sophisticated rebase commands/scripts.

Comment: you are not confused. I won't muddy the waters but I still need that trick for the things I was actually using it for, and you brought up a reminder that I dont have to specify the upstream for a normal rebase.  they both still have lots of other handy uses.